# Variable integer values

Tags: vb.net, button, fonts, integer, controls

this is only my second post here. I'm thoroughly enjoying my stay.

I'm having an issue with this code

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 7
    CType(Me.Controls.Find(String.Format("CheckBox{0}", i), True)(0), CheckBox).ForeColor = myFontDialog.Color
Next`
```

Basically the form that these controls are on are within a tab-control that has the options to remove pages that are not needed. Only problem is that if one of the pages is removed that has these controls on it, then I get an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" at run-time when selecting the fonts color.
I have tried using Tabpage1.visible = false but that does not actually remove the page tab from the control. I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to either make the integer range end in a varying integer or somehow make this easier on myself. I'm only an amateur coder so most of the more complex stuff is a bit over my head, but all the "answers" I found on google and other sites were of no use.

[I guess I can't embed images yet, so it made this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnxUe.png)

Comment: If the error occurs in the code you've shown that means that no check box was found by the specified name. You should store the resulting collection from `Me.Controls.Find(...)` in a variable and check if `Count` is at least 1 before trying to access the first item.

Comment: You say that these CheckBoxes are contained in a Form that is contained in a TabPage.  Presumably you are holding a reference to this Form so that you can execute code on it.  Removing the TabPage from the TabControl should not alter the contained Form unless the TabPage is disposed that would also cause its contained controls to be disposed.  That said, a Form has a boolean property named `IsDisposed` that you could use to control the execution of the subject code.  Alternatively, you could check the form's `Controls` collection `Count` property to see if it is greater than zero.

Comment: So the tab control is the main area of the parent windows form. I tried using what Mary posted below, either i'm dumb and am not doing it right or that will not work for what I am trying to accomplish. I've also looked into the `IsDisposed` property and I can't seem to find that in the tab-control properties. Again, I thank you guys for your input. I've added a screenshot of the main form with highlights of what is changing and what is not into the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a list of check boxes and remove the appropriate ones on the closed tabs. Then when you wan to change a property, just loop through the list.

```
Private lstCheck As List(Of CheckBox)
    Private Sub CreateCheckBoxesList()
        lstCheck = New List(Of CheckBox) From {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6, CheckBox7}
    End Sub
    Private Sub CloseTab(TabIndexClosed As Integer)
        Select Case TabIndexClosed
            Case 0
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox1)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox2)
            Case 1
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox3)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox4)
            Case 2
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox5)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox6)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox7)
        End Select
    End Sub
    Private Sub ChangeCheckBoxColor()
        For Each chk As CheckBox In lstCheck
            chk.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Next
    End Sub
```

Edited based on comments:
Here is another example that depends on event procedures. The list is created in the Form.Load method. I added calls to CloseTab and AddTab to your ToolStrip. These calls update the check box list. I added a button to the form for changing the text color of the check boxes.

```
Private lstCheck As List(Of CheckBox)

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CreateCheckBoxesList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateCheckBoxesList()
        lstCheck = New List(Of CheckBox) From {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6, CheckBox7}
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseTab(TabIndexClosed As String)
        Select Case TabIndexClosed
            Case "Tab1"
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox1)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox2)
            Case "Tab2"
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox3)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox4)
            Case "Tab3"
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox5)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox6)
                lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox7)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddTab(TabAdded As String)
        Select Case TabAdded
            Case "Tab1"
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox1)
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox2)
            Case "Tab2"
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox3)
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox4)
            Case "Tab3"
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox5)
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox6)
                lstCheck.Add(CheckBox7)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRed.Click
        For Each chk As CheckBox In lstCheck
            chk.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage1)
            CloseTab("Tab1)")
        End If
        If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.CheckState = 0 Then
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPage1)
            AddTab("Tab1")
        End If
    End Sub
```

I just relized from the name of your tool strip that this might be a WPF application, in which case all bets are off. I assumed Windows Forms. That would have been good infor to include in your question. This might work but it is designed for WinForms.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing this correctly as I don't understand how this stops the boxes from returning null values, thus causing the outside the bounds of the array error. I appreciate your help here though, I just am a little outside my skill range apparently.
Also how does this see what pages are closed and which are open and available?

Comment: You are right. The CloseTab sub won't work correctly because the indexes will change. I will update my code. The idea is to maintain a list of Check Boxes removing the check boxes that are on the tab being closed by the user. Then you can loop through the list with only the check boxes that remain. What event do you use to allow the user to remove tabs?

Comment: Currently it is a toolstrip menu item. Here is the code
Private Sub HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage1)
        If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.CheckState = 0 Then TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPage1)
    End Sub

Comment: Currently it is a toolstrip menu item.
I tried pasting the event to hide the page here but it seems to not like that.

Comment: I was actually not aware what type of application this is, It kind of got dropped in my lap for something at work. I was under the impression that it was a WinForm application, is there a way to check??

Comment: Yes, right click on the name of the application in Solution Explorer. On the context menu choose Properties. Select the Application tab. There is a box labeled Application Type.

Comment: Oh derp, it is a Windows Forms Application, I was able to get your second block of code to work. Now it changes the appearance of everything in the form regardless if it's visible or not. Thank you again your your assistance, you have saved my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comments: Here is another example that depends on event procedures. The list is created in the Form.Load method. I added calls to CloseTab and AddTab to your ToolStrip. These calls update the check box list. I added a button to the form for changing the text color of the check boxes.

Private lstCheck As List(Of CheckBox)

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateCheckBoxesList()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateCheckBoxesList()
    lstCheck = New List(Of CheckBox) From {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6, CheckBox7}
End Sub

Private Sub CloseTab(TabIndexClosed As String)
    Select Case TabIndexClosed
        Case "Tab1"
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox1)
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox2)
        Case "Tab2"
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox3)
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox4)
        Case "Tab3"
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox5)
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox6)
            lstCheck.Remove(CheckBox7)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub AddTab(TabAdded As String)
    Select Case TabAdded
        Case "Tab1"
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox1)
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox2)
        Case "Tab2"
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox3)
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox4)
        Case "Tab3"
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox5)
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox6)
            lstCheck.Add(CheckBox7)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub btnRed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRed.Click
    For Each chk As CheckBox In lstCheck
        chk.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage1)
        CloseTab("Tab1)")
    End If
    If HideRouterFormatterToolStripMenuItem.CheckState = 0 Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPage1)
        AddTab("Tab1")
    End If
End Sub
```